# How to echo multiple images using an Array

Tags: php, arrays, image

Using this code:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT pdimg1 FROM products WHERE pdcat LIKE 'fashion%'");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$img1 = '';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $Rpdimg1 = $row['pdimg1'];
    $img1 .= $Rpdimg1;
}

UPDATED TO INCLUDE BELOW:
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE pdcat LIKE 'collectibles%'");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$img2 = '';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $Rpdimg2 = htmlspecialchars($row['pdimg1']);
    $img2 .= $Rpdimg2;
}

$cats = array(
            array(
                "title" => "FASHION",
                "img" => $img1
            ),
            array(
                "title" => "COLLECTIBLES & ART",
                "img" => $img2,
            )
        );

foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
    <?php echo $cat["title"]; ?>
    <img src="images/<?php echo $cat["img"]; ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I get this result displayed in Inspector Tools on Firefox:

```
<img src="images/shirt.jpgpants.jpg">

[But on the webpage, this displays as a broken image.]
```

**But what I *want* is this result:**

```
<img src="images/shirt.jpg">
<img src="images/pants.jpg">

[However, I would like the above results displayed as IMAGES, not as html text.]
```

Those two images are values echoed from my database. They are from my `products` table:

```
pdid | pdimg1
-----------------
  1  | shirt.jpg
  2  | pants.jpg
```

So basically

1) I'm selecting rows from my database table `products`

2) I'm inserting them as variables into an array (which is used for other purposes)

3) I'm using a foreach loop to echo out those variables from that array

4) Now the problem lies in that those IMAGE variables bunch together as a SINGLE WORD (`shirt.jpgpants.jpg`) instead of as separated values, and do not get encased in their OWN `img` tags, but are bunched together under the same `img` tag.

5) So I demonstrated above in **bold text** the result that I wanted. How would I achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do array assignment inside loop, and bit reduced code like below:

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT pdimg1 FROM products WHERE pdcat LIKE 'fashion%'");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$cats = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cats[] = array(
    "title" => $row['title'];
    "img" => $row['pdimg1']; 
   ); // you can add as many column as you get from query
}

foreach ($cats as $cat): ?>
    <?php echo $cat["title"]; ?>
   <img src="images/<?php echo $cat["img"]; ?>">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: okay so I found the issue was that the semicolon after the echoed out rows was unneeded. I omitted that and the code worked, so thank you for resolving this!

Answer (score 2):

Use an extra multidimensional array variable. like this

```
<?php
$int_data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) { 

    $int_data[] = array(
        "title" => $row['title'];
        "image" => $row['pdimg1']; 
    );
}
?>
```

Now display the `title` and `image` using `foreach loop`

```
<?php
foreach ($int_data as $data) { ?> 
  Title : <?php echo $data['title]; ?> <br/>
  Image : <img src="path/<?php echo $data['image]; ?>"> <br/>
<?php
} ?>
```

Comment: yeah I'm not sure why but this is not displaying anything. I'm getting the same result with Anat's code

Comment: This is strange.. I'm looking at the source code and it's empty

Comment: Before 1st loop, print the query output data like this `print_r($rows)`;

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT pdimg1 FROM products WHERE pdcat LIKE 'fashion%'");
     $stmt->execute();
     $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
     foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
        <img src="images/<?= $row['pdimg1']; ?>">
  <?php }  ?>
```